# Algebraic independence and unique factorization in the Selberg class

Tags: nt.number-theory

One can read in this link: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02638380
that if $F$ and $G$ are distinct primitive elements of $\mathcal{S}$, then the transcendence degree of $\mathbb{C}[F,G]$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is two. Denote by $A$ this statement. What could be the easiest to prove statement $B$ such that the conjunction of $A$ and $B$ implies that $\mathcal{S}$ has unique factorization?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean this mainly as a general algebraic question or for the Selberg class specifically. That is, should this B also be applicable to other semigroups (with suitable restrictions). 

Comment: A meta-question/comment: it could make sense to create a tag 'selberg-class' as there are various questions on the site related to it and to then (over time, *not all at once*) tag old existing ones with it too. Since many of these questions are by you, your opinion (also perhaps your willingness to do this) on this seems crucial. [I assume you know you can create tags, just by using them.]

Comment: Indeed this idea of creating a tag dedicated to the Selberg class is a good one. As for your first comment, I'm essentially interested in the Selberg class, and not really in other semigroups.

Comment: Why should algebraic independence be related to unique factorization?

Comment: Jerzy Jaczorowski, Giuseppe Molteni and Alberto Perelli proved in 1999 that unique factorization in $\mathcal{S}$ is equivalent to algebraic independence of distinct primitive members of $\mathcal{S}$ over the ring of $p$-finite Dirichlet series, which I guess is a conjectured generalization of the algebraic independence mentionned in the link above. Hence my question.

Comment: Thx. I'd guess one expects even some joint universality, which is way stronger than algebraic indepence.